# send email when number is below threshold

Tags: php

In my mysql database I have a column called `voorraad` and `threshold`.
When the `voorraad` drops below the specified threshold it needs to send an email saying voorraad is below the threshold.

I can do that, but how can I make sure it only sends one email until it reaches below threshold again.

When using this code...

```
if  voorraad < threshold{
send email
}
```

...it keeps sending emails since the voorraad can stay below threshold for like a few days. So it needs to send the email only one time until voorraad reaches or goes above the threshold.

Once it drops below the threshold again it needs to send the same email again.

Comment: Define a `email_sent` column in the table, set it to default `1` or `null`. Then you need some trigger logic that checks if the `voorraad` is below `threshold` when the data gets inserted/updated. If that's the case, set it to 0. As soon as you send the mail, update `email_sent` to 1. Then keep checking with the trigger when the values change. If the value changes, and goes below `voorraad < threshold` again, set it to 0. Then you periodically pull data where `email_sent = 0 and voorraad < threshold` and send the emails (where you update `email_sent` as previously mentioned).

Comment: You need to maintain some flag in the database whether mail is sent or not.or you  can store mail sent date so if you want to send mail every day or every week once if the value is still less.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to determine if an email has been sent already.

Similar to what @qeril wrote.

1. Create a column in your table similar to `email_sent` as a tiny integer with default set to 0
2. When `voorraad` drops below threshold:

a) check value of `email_sent`

b) `if(email_sent == 0) { send email }` and update value of `email_sent` to 1

3. When `voorraad` rises above threshold update value of `email_sent` to 0

Step three (3) resets and is ready to send an email once more when `voorraad` drops below the threshold again

**EDIT**

I can't give you specific code since you haven't provided the actual code you are using, but it would look something like this:

```
$voorraad = $result['voorraad'];
$threshold = $result['threshold'];
$sent_email = $result['sent_email'];

if($voorraad < $threshold) {
    if($sent_email == 0) {
        //send email code;
        //update 'sent_email` to 1;
    }
} else { if($voorraad >= $threshold) {
    //update 'sent_email' to 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you but when I do like checking if if voorraad > threshold{email_send = 0} than it would really take a lot of computing power because it constantly does that if statement.

Comment: What do you mean _constantly_? Is this running as a cron job? If so, how often are you running it? We can't really give you any **specific** help unless you show us the actual code your are using. Please edit your question and show us the code you are using.

Comment: You only need to run this script/code (*check if the stock is below threshold*) when the stock is being altered, e.g. a sale or a restock happend. You don't have to check/verify the stock 24/7

Comment: @DarkBee ... thank you for helping to clear up what the word "voorraad" means. This is why in many places on SO it is recommended to write code in English, even if it is not your native language. It helps others more easily assist you. :)